# The included urlconf xxxx.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

I want to get an url in a modelform class.
I have seen in
[The included urlconf manager.urls doesn't have any patterns in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482573/the-included-urlconf-manager-urls-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it). But **reverse_lazy** function not work for my case.

My case:

**captchahelper** is an **app** in **root**.

**root urlpatterns (urls.py under root project):**

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    .....
    # captcha
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captchahelper.urls')),
    .....
}
```

**captcha urlpatterns(urls.py under captchahelper project):**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.captcha , name="views_captcha"),
    url(r'^refresh/$', views.refresh , name="views_refresh_captcha"),
)
```

**view.py under captchahelper project**

```
def captcha(request):
    .....
    return HttpResponse(captcha.gen_img_by_code(code),'image/jpeg')
```

get:

```
class CaptchaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .....
    captcha = Captcha()
    encoded = captcha.get_encrypt_code()
    captcha_image = urlresolvers.reverse_lazy('views_captcha') + '?encoded='+encoded
    .....
    def clean_captcha_text(self):
        ....
```

turn out error:
/account/signup/  is current url(also include in root.urls),when a visitor views this page,above class will be init in the corresponding view function.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /account/signup/
The included urlconf root.urls doesn't have any patterns in it


D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) ...
 ▼ Local vars
    Variable    Value
    ns_pattern  
    ''
    viewname    
    'views_captcha'
    args    
    []
    current_app 
    None
    prefix  
    u'/'
    parts   
    ['views_captcha']
    resolver    
    <RegexURLResolver root.urls (None:None) ^/>
    kwargs  
    {}
    path    
    []
    resolved_path   
    []
    urlconf 
    'root.urls'
    view    
    'views_captcha'
```

I just feel django is so complex ,because I come from ASP MVC3.I can easy generate an url with querystring from a statement like  `Url.Action("CaptchaController", "CaptchaView", new { encoded = "encoded"})` in MVC3.But If I want to generate a url with querystring in django, the code will be `reverse('captcha') + '?encoded=' + encoded`.It is really ugly....

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the class, not the def method itself in your urls file.  Your project seems a little odd, since most files have a `*.py` ending, but here's an example from a project I'm already using:

```
urls.py
...
url(r'^getCustomerData/$', views.getCustomerData),
...
```

and in `views.py,

```
from app.models import Customer

def getCustomerData(request):
//process and return
```

So for you, I'd suggest changing your url resolver from

```
url(r'^$', views.captcha , name="views_captcha"),
url(r'^refresh/$', views.refresh , name="views_refresh_captcha")
```

to

```
url(r'^$', views.captcha.CAPTCHA_HANDLER_DEF , name="views_captcha"),
url(r'^refresh/$', views.captcha.refresh , name="views_refresh_captcha")
```

and define those two functions within captcha.

Comment: `views.captcha` is my view function,`root.urls` is urls.py under root project

Comment: Hmm.  Are you calling `captcha` from the url `/account/signup/`?  If so, you need to add that the the url in captchahelper.

Comment: Also, do you have `captchahelper` defined as an installed application in `settings.py`?

Comment: the flow is: `/account/signup/` will call `signup` view. `signup` view instantiate `CaptchaForm`.Then `reverse` excute when `CaptchaForm` init.And certainly I have added `captchahelper` to APP_LIST.I think it is no relevent with the viewing url, because routes has already defined which must can be retrieved.

Comment: Have you tried adding `/account/signup/` in the captcha url paths?  If you're calling `captcha` from the signup view, then your url is `/accounts/signup/captcha/`

Comment: I can directly access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/captcha/?encoded=xxxxxx`.That url works fine,return a captcha image.`/accounts/signup/captcha/` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you your urls.py file has `urlpatterns` in it and is spelt correctly.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.article_list),
]
```