# The Urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it when using {% url %} tags on production server

Tags: django, heroku, urlconf

I'm having trouble understanding why my url tags in my base.html: Login generate an exception when working on the heroku production server. When loading the page, I receive an error stating that "The included urlconf xxxxx.urls doesn't have any patterns in it." I discovered that I might need to use reverse_lazy (info taken from this post: [The included urlconf manager.urls doesn't have any patterns in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482573/the-included-urlconf-manager-urls-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it)), but I have no idea how to use it for non-generic views and I don't believe it'll have an effect on {% url %} tags anyways. It seems quite odd that my code works on the development server but generates this error on the production server. Here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', views.mylogin),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.mylogout,),
    url(r'^$', views.sign_up, name = "home"),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),)
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated as I've been quite stuck on this problem. Thanks!

Here's some of my html:

```
<a href = "{% url 'apps.login_auth.views.mylogin' %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: Same here.  What version of Django?  Is the Heroku buildpack using 'run_gunicorn' to serve the site?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the debug_toolbar installed? I had the same issue, but once I removed that, the message went away.
https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/521