# Django, redirected url is not proper

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and I am creating a form,

```
#forms.py
class SetupForm(forms.Form):
    pass
```

and corresponding view is

```
#views.py
class SetupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template/setup_form.html'
    form_class = SetupForm
    success_url = 'template/base_collect'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        return super(SetupView, self).form_valid(form)

def base(request):
    return render_to_response('template/base_collect.html')
```

and url patterns are,

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(url(r'^setup-form/$', views.SetupView.as_view(), name='setup-form'),
                   url(r'^base_collect/$', views.base),)
```

After submitting the form, the redirected URL is shown as

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/template/setup-form/template/base_collect.html` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/template/base_collect`.

What am I missing here? How to achieve later?

Comment: `success_url` must be an url, not a template name

Comment: Sorry i gave wrong url. I have modified the redirected URL. Pls check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify as below :

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^setup-form/$', views.SetupView.as_view(), name='setup-form'),
    url(r'^base_collect/$', views.base, name = 'base-form'),
)
```

And

Replace

```
success_url = 'template/base_collect.html'
```

with

```
success_url = reverse('base-form')
```

**Import**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

In your views.py

Comment: Hi, I am getting exception like, `The included urlconf myapp.urls doesn't have any patterns in it`

Comment: Edit and Paste error displayed . Its seems error is at different line .

Comment: Hi, It solved the error with reverse_lazy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482573/the-included-urlconf-manager-urls-doesnt-have-any-patterns-in-it

Comment: Nice .Thanks for update, Learnt about `reverse_lazy` . Didn't aware of it before .

Answer (score 1):

You mistakenly put the template name in the `success_url` property for the class. You also don't need the other two methods, as they aren't adding any functionality to what the default `FormView` class provides.

```
class SetupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template/setup_form.html'
    form_class = SetupForm
    success_url = 'collect/base_collect'  # the URL goes here

    #def form_valid(self,form):
    #    return super(SetupView, self).form_valid(form)
    #def base(request):
    #    return render_to_response('template/base_collect.html')
```

Comment: Sorry i gave wrong url. I have modified the redirected URL. Pls check it again.

Comment: Are you sure your URL is `template/base_collect`?

Comment: Yes. it is correct. 'template' is a directory name.

Comment: `template/base_collect` needs to be a _view pattern_, not a directory.  In other words, it needs to be mapped in your `urls.py` somewhere. You cannot direct to a "file".  Please update your question and describe what you are trying to do. Do you want to save the results from the form somewhere on the file system?

Comment: thanks, I tried with `template/base_collect`. It is redirecting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/template/setup-form/template/base_collect`